# How to delete my follower at github?

Tags: github, github-api

Is it possible to do?

If yes, could you please provide a [curl](http://curl.haxx.se) example?

Comment: I am sorry Geirby, it's a bit unclear for me to understand if you really want to delete all your followers in github and why curl would help with that... Stackoverflow helps people with specific programming/code questions. If you can add more details into your question (or another question), perhaps people will be able to help you.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Removing a follower on Github in fact *is* possible with this workaround:

Block the user who watches you, as described [in the github help](https://help.github.com/articles/blocking-a-user-from-your-personal-account/).

Then unblock him again.

After that he will not be blocked anymore and he will also no longer follow you.

Comment: 2016/10 Update link above https://help.github.com/articles/blocking-a-user-from-your-personal-account/

Comment: For those wondering, Github will not inform the blocked user that you've blocked them. "You can block a user in your account settings or from the user's profile. GitHub will not notify the user when you block them." (from the link above)

Answer (score 3):

Wrote to Github support:

> Is there any way to delete followers? I know about "Block User" option but it's not exactly what I want. Github API methods are also suitable.

They answered:

> No, this isn't currently possible.

So, there is no way for now. Only "Block User".

Answer (score 0):

Manually: go to user [profile](https://github.com/TomasVotruba) - in the right corner there is *Follow user* and right next to it menu with *Block user*/*Report user*.

By clicking on *Block user*, he was removed from my followers.

Here is [Github manual to do that](https://help.github.com/articles/blocking-a-user/).

Could not find an api alternative.

Comment: Thanks Tomáš, but it's not exaclty what I was looking for. Blocking seems to be too radical =)

Comment: There's no other way to remove follower. What exactly do you need that for?

Comment: Now I know that it's impossible (wrote to github support). Wanted just to remove my only one follower, didn't want him to see my "Hello word" repositories.

Comment: Why don't you want him to see it? Some sensitive data?

Answer (score 0):

These would be the `curl` commands, you were looking for:

**Block a user**<sup>1</sup>

```bash
$ curl \
  -X PUT \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer <YOUR-TOKEN>" \
  https://api.github.com/user/blocks/USERNAME
```

**Unblock a user**<sup>2</sup>

```bash
$ curl \
  -X DELETE \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer <YOUR-TOKEN>" \
  https://api.github.com/user/blocks/USERNAME
```

---

<sup>1</sup> https://docs.github.com/en/rest/users/blocking#block-a-user
<sup>2</sup> https://docs.github.com/en/rest/users/blocking#unblock-a-user